# How to aggregate a binary raster into percentage in R

Tags: r, matrix, gis, raster, r-raster

I have a binary raster(r) at 1 meter resolution and I want to convert it into a percentage value at 4m resolution.This new raster would have each pixel value representing the percent, calculated on basis of total frequency of 1 out of 16 pixels.I looked at the `raster` package which has `aggregate` function. However, this doesn't work.

```
   newras <-aggregate(r, fact=4,  fun= percent)
```

Comment: Converting to 4m resolution would aggregate 16 cells into each new cell, not 4.  Would your original raster always have a multiple of four cells in each dimension?

Comment: My original raster might not have a multiple of four cell but I can resize it to match the 4m resolution.

Comment: Please give a reproducible example so that it's easier to help

Comment: There is no need for downloading data. You need to set up an example in your question. It is your question, you should not make others do unnecessary work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do does not work because there is no function called `percentage`. But you can make one. In this case, the mean value is the fraction, so you multiply that with 100 to get the percentage.

Example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster()
set.seed(0)
values(r) <- sample(0:1, ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
```

Aggregate

```
a <- aggregate(r, 4, fun=function(x,...) 100 * mean(x))   
# or 
a <- 100 * aggregate(r, 4, mean)
```

Consider `NA` values

```
r[sample(ncell(r), 0.9 * ncell(r))] <- NA

# Make a function and use it    
percentage <- function(x, ...) { x <- na.omit(x); 100 * mean(x) }
a <- aggregate(r, 4, fun=percentage)

# or do
a <- 100 * aggregate(r, 4, fun=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method just using matrices.  I am using a 40 by 40 matrix.  The method will require some thought if dimensions are not multiples of 4.

Original matrix:

```
mtx <- matrix(sample(0:1, 40^2, TRUE), 40, 40)
```

Indices to use as arguments for grouping:

```
inds <- Map(seq, seq(1, 37, 4), seq(4, 40, 4))
```

Group into 4 by 4 blocks.  `blockarray` has 16 rows (each element within groups) and 100 columns (representing groups).  Note that 40 x 40 = 16 x 100.

```
blockarray <- mapply(function(i, j) mtx[i, j],
                     rep(inds, times = 10),
                     rep(inds, each = 10))
```

To get the percentage matrix:

```
pcts <- matrix(colMeans(blockarray)*100, 10, 10)
```

Visual inspection of results:

```
image(mtx, zlim = 0:1, col = c("white", "black"))
image(pcts, zlim = c(0, 100), col = colorRampPalette(c("white", "black"))(11))
```

Validation of results:

```
sum(mtx[1:4, 5:8])/16*100
pcts[1, 2]
```